# Internationalization inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I have a JSP page, which accepts user strings in more than 23 languages. So an English speaking user writes `8.5`, and the JavaScript function should accept it as well as the input `8,5` from a Russian user.

In this scenario, how do we validate the input in JavaScript for all the languages?

Comment: My idea is first get the locale value then the number format value and then validate with user input and if matches return appropriate vale.I think I need a snippet for this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do this server side with Java using java.text.NumberFormat, but Dojo has code to do this client side.  See [dojo.number](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3/dojo.number) and [dijit.form.NumberTextBox](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/form/NumberTextBox) which uses dojo.number.