# How does internationalization work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I'm wondering how to deal internationalization in JavaScript. I googled but I'm not getting convincing answers for:

- Does JavaScript have native support for internationalization?
- What is i18n in JavaScript?
- How to deal with calendars, currencies, dates, etc.?

I've already read [Internationalization inside JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934175/internationalization-inside-javascript).

Comment: Microsoft has recently released a jquery globalization plugin. The details are [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx)

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Localization support in legacy browsers is poor.  Originally, this was due to phrases in the `ECMAScript` language spec that look like this:

> **Number.prototype.toLocaleString()**
> Produces a string value that represents the value of the Number formatted according to the
> conventions of the host environment’s current locale. This function is implementation-dependent, and
> it is permissible, but not encouraged, for it to return the same thing as **toString**.

Every localization method defined in the spec is defined as "implementation-dependent", which results in a lot of inconsistencies.  In this instance, Chrome Opera and Safari would return the same thing as `.toString()`.  Firefox and IE will return locale formatted strings, and IE even includes a thousand separator (perfect for currency strings).  Chrome was recently updated to return a thousands-separated string, though with no fixed decimal.

**For modern environments**, the [ECMAScript Internationalization API spec](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/), a new standard that complements the ECMAScript Language spec, provides much better support for string comparison, number formatting, and the date and time formatting; it also fixes the corresponding functions in the Language Spec. An introduction can be found [here](http://norbertlindenberg.com/2012/10/ecmascript-internationalization-api/index.html). Implementations are available in:

- Chrome 24
- Firefox 29
- Internet Explorer 11
- Opera 15

There is also a compatibility implementation, [Intl.js](http://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js), which will provide the API in environments where it doesn't already exist.

Determining the user's preferred language remains a problem since there's no specification for obtaining the current language.  Each browser implements a method to obtain a language string, but this could be based on the user's operating system language or just the language of the browser:

```
// navigator.userLanguage for IE, navigator.language for others
var lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
```

A good workaround for this is to dump the Accept-Language header from the server to the client.  If formatted as a JavaScript, it can be passed to the Internationalization API constructors, which will automatically pick the best (or first-supported) locale.

In short, you have to put in a lot of the work yourself, or use a [framework/library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx), because you cannot rely on the browser to do it for you.

Various libraries and plugins for localization:

- Mantained by an [open community](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control) (no order):

- [Polyglot.js](http://airbnb.io/polyglot.js/) - AirBnb's internationalization library
- [Intl.js](http://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js) - a compatibility implementation of the Internationalisation API
- [i18next](https://github.com/i18next/i18next) ([home](http://i18next.com/)) for i18n (incl. jquery plugin, translation ui,...)
- [moment.js](https://github.com/moment/moment/) ([home](http://momentjs.com/)) for dates
- [numbro.js](https://github.com/foretagsplatsen/numbro) ([home](http://numbrojs.com/)) (was [numeral.js](https://github.com/adamwdraper/Numeral-js) ([home](http://numeraljs.com/))) for numbers and currency
- [l10n.js](https://github.com/eligrey/l10n.js/#readme)  ([home](http://eligrey.com/blog/post/localization-in-javascript))
- [L10ns](https://github.com/tinganho/l10ns) ([home](http://l10ns.org)) tool for i18n workflow and complex string formatting
- [jQuery Localisation (plugin)](https://github.com/kbwood/localisation)  ([home](http://keith-wood.name/localisation.html))
- [YUI Internationalization support](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/intl/)
- [jquery.i18Now](https://github.com/mbitto/jquery.i18Now) for dates
- [browser-i18n](https://github.com/gammasoft/browser-i18n) with support to pluralization
- [counterpart](https://github.com/martinandert/counterpart) is inspired by Ruby's famous [I18n gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n)
- [jQuery Globalize](http://blog.jquery.com/2015/04/23/announcing-globalize-1-0/) jQuery's own i18n library
- [js-lingui](https://github.com/lingui/js-lingui/) - MessageFormat implementation for JS (ES2016) and React

- Others:

- [jQuery Globalization (plugin)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx)
- [requirejs-i18n](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#i18n) Define an I18N Bundle with RequireJS.

Feel free to add/edit.

Comment: Thanks to all the people contributing; I'd never have thought I could learn something by reading my old answers.  I'm glad to see the update for Internationalization API spec in there, that's really awesome and I just got to test drive it in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent compilation. On a positive note, it looks like Mozilla might ship a modern toLocaleString() soon – possibly FF28: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=769871

Comment: http://i18next.com now comes with a translation management built on top http://locize.com - this might be a big win if you need to solve the complete translation process - not just instrument your code for i18n. Plus has a nice Incontext Editor feature...

Comment: Localisation as implemented by ECMA-402 conflates language and formatting to the extent that it's almost useless. The two are completely separate concerns. I guess if you just want a quick and easy solution it "works", but the notion that numbers or dates should be formatted for a particular language without any prior idea of the result is not conducive to good programming.

Answer (score 13):

Mozilla recently released the awesome L20n or localization 2.0. In their own words L20n is

> an open source, localization-specific scripting language used to process gender, plurals, conjugations, and most of the other quirky elements of natural language.

Their js implementation is on the [github L20n repository.](https://github.com/l20n/l20n.js)

Comment: I have started a project which needs localization and we have decided to use L20n too ;). So I have wrotten a first version of a L20n Plugin for RequireJS (https://github.com/fernandogmar/L20n-RequireJS) in case you use RequireJS I hope it would be useful for you too. Any suggestion will be welcomed.

Comment: This is deprecated for https://www.projectfluent.org/ now

Answer (score 0):

Some of it is native, the rest is available through libraries.

For example [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) is a good international date library.

For the rest, it's just about language translation, and JavaScript is natively Unicode compatible (as well as all major browsers).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try another library - https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.i18n .

In addition to parameter replacement and multiple plural forms, it has support for gender a rather unique feature of custom grammar rules that some languages need.