# Internationalization in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have a legacy JSF application. Now that we want to add i18n support to the application. Some portion of the textual content comes from javascript code and is added dynamically. How do we best internationalize this? The approach that i have in mind is to get the entire resource bundle as a json object from a server side script and then use jsonobj.propname wherever needed.

Is this is a right approach? Do you have any better solution?

Comment: Where do you want to i18n support in JavaScript or in JSF? because JSF != JavaScript. JSF is server code and JavaScript is client code. If you really mean Javascript this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084675/internationalization-in-javascript

Comment: Javascript of course. Anyways, thanks for the link. Will check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That certainly sounds like an approach that will work.

A commercial application I worked on generated a separate JavaScript library for each language as part of the build process. This was done for performance reasons - the results were minified, a single file reduced latency and the results were cached "forever." But not every application has such tight constraints.