# How to add internationalization support to Blogger?

Tags: javascript, html, internationalization, blogger

How to add internationalization support to Blogger?
Is it possible to deal with multiple languages within one blog?
Is it possible to add own translation and don't use [Google Translate widget](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These should be set in html head of your blog (Design -> Edit HTML, insert after <head>)

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script src='http://csjs.googlecode.com/files/csjs_1.1.3.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://csjs.googlecode.com/files/csjs.lang_1.0.0.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://csjs.googlecode.com/files/csjs.browser_1.0.3.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://csjs.googlecode.com/files/csjs.i18n_1.2.5.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://csjs.googlecode.com/files/csjs.ui_1.0.6.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://csjs.googlecode.com/files/csjs.ui.i18n_1.0.4.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

This is very post looks like:

```
<!-- insert this as a title -->
<div i18n='post1_msg1'> <!-- it is worth to add default text here due to some programs that --></div>

<!-- any HTML controls to be internationalized -->
<div i18n='post1_msg2'><!-- operate blog content (like rss reader) will not download script --></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    i18n.load( {
        'en' : {
            'post1_msg1' : 'First Post',
            'post1_msg2' : 'Post content'
        },
        'ru' : {
            'post1_msg1' : 'Первое сообщение',
            'post1_msg2' : 'Текст сообщения'
        },
        'uk' : {
            'post1_msg1' : 'Перше повідомлення',
            'post1_msg2' : 'Текст повідомлення'
        }
    });
</script>
```

Add language selector as a gadget (Design -> Page Elements -> Add a Gadget -> Basics -> HTML/JavaScript).

```
<div csjs-ctrl-class="csjs.ui.i18n.ListLanguageSwitch"></div>
```

[About csjs library](http://code.google.com/p/csjs/wiki/csjs_i18n).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for mobile version? Tested with Samsung Galaxy Note II

Answer (score 0):

found useful related discussions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48726/best-javascript-i18n-techniques-ajax-dates-times-numbers-currency
[How does internationalization work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084675/internationalization-in-javascript)