# Making internationalization work in blogger?

Tags: internationalization, blogger, blogspot, i18next

I'm referring to this page here:
http://phoexpert.blogspot.de/2015/08/why-am-i-doing-this.html?m=1

So in this blog post the author uses csjs library for internationalization (following the advice in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909879/how-to-add-internationalization-support-to-blogger) ). While it works in the browser version it doesn't work for mobile version.

I assume it has something to do with the query"?m=1" that is added to the URL for the mobile version. While on the Desktop I can delete the "?m=1" to get the desired version, I can't delete it in the mobile version?

So how can fix it? Is there another library besides csjs that works with blogger (I've searched and so far only the post I was referring in the beginning was the only reference)? Or is there a workaround?

More importantly, why does it actually happen? I thought it doesn't make a difference whether it's mobile or desktop version. I thought the only thing that matters is the browser size? Why does the query "?m=1" messes up with the internationalization?