# JQuery filterable plugin with i18n (collation) support

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization, collation, non-ascii-characters

I have searched without success a JQuery plugin able to filter an HTML list (list of `li`, `div` or others) based on its content. I found numerous ones, but none of them seems to support what's called collation in MySQL (and certainly in other places).

For those not familiar with this concept, collation is the way some characters in foreign languages (other than English, I mean) are considered equivalent. For instance, in French, filtering for *‘Éléphant’*, *‘éléphant’* or *‘elephant’* should give you identical results. It's a kind of lax filtering where derived accented characters like *‘é’*, *‘è’*, *‘ê’* and *‘ë’* are considered equivalent to the unaccented letter *‘e’*.

This question is quite linked to this other one: [How does internationalization work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084675/internationalization-in-javascript).

My question is double:

- Does somebody have a good pointer on this unfindable plugin (tired of playing [Indy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Jones_and_the_Last_Crusade) in the JQuery plugins jungle to find the graal and I haven't brought my whip)?
- Failing that, I will be glad with some good tips or resources on which is the easiest way to build this sort of mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already looked at https://github.com/Teradata/lasca ?

Seems to fit or at least to be a starting point for implementing a jquery plugin.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, great start. Haven't found it before. Have you googled it or did you know it before? No completely what I need: perfect String match with compare, no regexp or partial match (seems difficult to achieve). Commited 7 months ago without activity since, but still a good start. Didn't know [UCA Collation Tables](http://www.unicode.org/charts/uca/) before.

Comment: oh and if you will publish a own plugin - let us know - might be handy some day

Comment: Ok, you've been smarter than me for in your Googling. Don't really know if I will have the time to work on this, not a top priority demand of my employer, but will tell you if something concrete is made.

Comment: I have used the given piece of code and it works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the searched JQuery plugin, but it seems that the [new Internationalization API specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/JavaScript_technologies_overview?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/JavaScript_technologies_overview#Internationalization_API) embraces the expressed needs with for instance collation handling.