# Put the image src from the clicked element image src and update data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I don't know how to explain this because I am an amateur.

I have a language menu with 6 languages: `Es, Br, Fr, It, De, En`

So, I have the default language selected EN and a dropdown with the rest of the images.

The question is: how can I update the text and the image when I click on It (for example).

**My structure is like this:**

```js
$(".dropbtn, .burger").click(function() {
  $(this).next(".dropdown-content, .items").stop().slideToggle(500);
  //$(this).find(".arrow-up, .arrow-down").toggle();
});

// If you click outside dropdown - close dropdown
var $menu = $('.dropdown');
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  if (!$menu.is(e.target) && $menu.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $('.dropdown-content').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">
  <img src="assets/img/languages/flag_en.png" alt=""> EN
  <span class="ico ico-pointer_down"></span>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-content" id="dd-content">
  <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_br.png" alt=""> PT</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_es.png" alt=""> ES</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_fr.png" alt=""> FR</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_de.png" alt=""> DE</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_it.png" alt=""> IT</a>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using any libraries for the dropdown? If not then why are you not using <select> ?

Comment: For details on how to implement internationalization see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084675/how-does-internationalization-work-in-javascript

Comment: @Kay The op's question is different from the link that you have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the text in the `span` like :

```
<span class="lang">EN</span>
```

And attach click event then on click copy the text and image to the `.dropbtn` and hide the clicked anchor using `hide` class and finally remove the class `hide` from all the other anchors, like :

```js
$(".dropbtn").click(function() {
  $(this).next(".dropdown-content, .items").stop().slideToggle(500);
});

// If you click outside dropdown - close dropdown
var $menu = $('.dropdown');
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  if (!$menu.is(e.target) && $menu.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $('.dropdown-content').hide();
  }
});

$("#dd-content a").click(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  var img = $(this).find('img').clone(true);

  $('.dropbtn .lang').text(text);
  $('.dropbtn img').replaceWith(img);

  $("#dd-content a").removeClass('hide');
  $(this).addClass('hide');
});
```

```css
a.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">
  <img src="assets/img/languages/flag_en.png" alt=""><span class="lang">EN</span>
  <span class="ico ico-pointer_down"></span>
</a>

<div class="dropdown-content" id="dd-content">
  <a href="#" class="hide"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_en.png" alt=""> EN</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_br.png" alt=""> PT</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_es.png" alt=""> ES</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_fr.png" alt=""> FR</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_de.png" alt=""> DE</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_it.png" alt=""> IT</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for ?

Comment: more or less. first, thank you.
second: If I click on dropdown option (FR) the span.lang update but the image from dropdown option disappear. I don't want this

Comment: Very awesome, one last thing. Can I make it to close after I click one of the options and make a cookie to keep my selection after refresh  ? Thank you

Comment: _Can I make it to close after I click one of the options_ It looks like it already does

Comment: _and make a cookie to keep my selection after refresh ?_ yes that possible you could try it and I will be here if you stuck... give it a try

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5D3wAE 
i've made this but dont work after refresh .. still got old language

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180934/discussion-between-stefan-iordache-and-zakaria-acharki).

Comment: Hi are you there ?

Comment: codeshare.io/5D3wAE i've made this but dont work after refresh .. still got old language

Comment: Yes I saw it and fixed it, just create new question and I'll answer it to keep things arranged.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577528/i-want-to-put-a-cookie-on-click-to-keep-my-selection-active-after-the-page-refre/52578015#52578015

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a `click` event-handler for your images.
You are using a `click` event-handler already.

```
$(".dropdown-content img").click(function (e) {});
```

Inside your event-handler you need to define what to do.
Your mission is to change the `src` attribute.
So what you need to do first is to save the attribute in a variable.

```
var src = $(this).attr("src");
```

Then you need to change the attribute of the image you want to change.

```
$(".dropbtn").attr("src", src); //<-- the first parameter defines the attribute you want to change.
//The second attribute is our variable we set earlier.
```

In the end, it should look like this:

```
$(".dropdown-content img").click(function (e) {
   var src = $(this).attr("src"); //<-- getting the attribute of the clicked element (this)
   $(".dropbtn").attr("src", src); //<-- changing the attribute.
});
```

There are a lot of guides out there that can help you out.

However, this is not best practise for internalization but might be good to learn some basic JQuery and JS rules.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the country name in a `span`. Then, when you click on the language options, swap out the image `src` and text for the chosen language.

I have added a little css to help illustrate the image src changing.

```js
$(".dropbtn, .burger").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next(".dropdown-content, .items").stop().slideToggle(500);
  //$(this).find(".arrow-up, .arrow-down").toggle();
});

// If you click outside dropdown - close dropdown
var $menu = $('.dropdown');
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  if (!$menu.is(e.target) && $menu.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $('.dropdown-content').hide();
  }
});

var $lang = $('.dropbtn');
//when user clicks on language
$('.dropdown-content').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this),
    $img = $this.find('img');
  //set the image of .dropbtn to the chosen image
  $lang.find('img').attr('src', $img.attr('src'));
  //set the name of the language
  $lang.find('.lang-name').text($this.text());
});
```

```css
<!-- added to help visualise the image src attribute changing. Can be safely ignored. -->
.dropbtn img:after {
  content: attr(src);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="dropbtn">
  <img src="assets/img/languages/flag_en.png" alt=""> <span class="lang-name">EN</span>
  <span class="ico ico-pointer_down"></span>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-content" id="dd-content">
  <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_br.png" alt=""> PT</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_es.png" alt=""> ES</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_fr.png" alt=""> FR</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_de.png" alt=""> DE</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_it.png" alt=""> IT</a>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not what I need. This only change the image but its incomplete. thanks