# I want to put a cookie on click to keep my selection active after the page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to put a cookie on click to keep my selection active after the page refresh and I have this code below:

I have tried different methods but I can't make it happen. I am a noob at javascript or jquery.

Look what I've tried till now. I have a function where I want to set the cookie and then I call that function on click event.

```js
$(function() {

  //LANGUAGE COOKIE
  function setLanguageCookie() {
    var expire = new Date();
    expire = new Date(expire.getTime() + 7776000000);
    document.cookie = "Language=Language; expires=" + expire;
  }

  // THIS IS FOR THE BURGER MENU TOGGLE
  $(".dropbtn").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".dropdown-content, .items").stop().slideToggle(500);
  });

  // If you click outside dropdown - close dropdown
  var $menu = $('.dropdown');
  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    if (!$menu.is(e.target) && $menu.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $('.dropdown-content').hide();
    }
  });

  $("#dd-content a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $(this).text();
    var img = $(this).find('img').clone(true);

    $('.dropbtn .lang').text(text);
    $('.dropbtn img').replaceWith(img);

    $("#dd-content a").removeClass('hide');
    $(this).addClass('hide');
    setLanguageCookie();
  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  background: #191919;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
  background: #000;
}

header .brand {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  header .brand {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

header .logo {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  header .logo {
    display: block;
  }
}

header .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 40px;
}

header .dropdown a.dropbtn {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

header .dropdown a.dropbtn .ico {
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 11px;
}

header .dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  header .dropdown {
    display: initial;
  }
}

header .dropdown a {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0 !important;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

header .dropdown-content a.hide {
  display: none;
}

header .dropdown a:hover {
  color: #999999 !important;
}

header .is-hidden {
  display: none;
}

header .actions {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

header .actions .dropdown a,
header .actions a.ml,
header .actions a.su {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

header .actions a.ml {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  header .actions a.ml {
    display: block;
  }
}

header .actions a.su {
  background: #ef2945;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

header .actions a.su:hover {
  background: #df4057;
}

header .menu-mobile .items {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 52px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(21, 21, 21, .98);
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

header .menu-mobile .items a {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 16px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0 none;
  background: transparent;
  height: 36px;
  align-items: center;
  color: #cbcbcb;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0e0e0e;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header .menu-mobile .items a span {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

header .menu-mobile {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

header .menu-mobile a.burger {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
}

header .actions .dropdown a.dropbtn img {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

header .actions .dropdown .dropdown-content a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

header .actions .dropdown .dropdown-content a img {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .menu-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <span class="logo">
    <img src="#" width="363" height="24" alt="">
  </span>
  <div class="brand">MY HEADER</div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">
        <img src="assets/img/languages/flag_en.png" alt="">
        <span class="lang">EN</span>
        <span class="ico ico-pointer_down"></span>
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="dd-content">
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_br.png" alt=""> PT</a>
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_es.png" alt=""> ES</a>
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_fr.png" alt=""> FR</a>
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_de.png" alt=""> DE</a>
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/languages/flag_it.png" alt=""> IT</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="ml">login</a>
    <a href="#" class="su">Join</a>

    <div class="menu-mobile">
      <a href="#" class="burger"><span class="ico ico-menu"></span></a>
      <div class="items">
        <a href="#">
          <span class="ico ico-user"></span> member login
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="ico ico-globe"></span> language
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

https://codepen.io/stefan-iordache/pen/JmdZvQ

Answer (score 0):

If your a tag is a real link then you should add an preventDefault call to your click event.
It will prevent the default link function to execute before you could set the cookie.

```
function setLanguageCookie() {
    var expire=new Date();
    expire=new Date(expire.getTime()+7776000000);
    document.cookie="Language=Language; expires="+expire;
}
// THIS IS FOR THE BURGER MENU TOGGLE
$(".dropbtn").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".dropdown-content, .items").stop().slideToggle(500);
});
// If you click outside dropdown - close dropdown
var $menu = $('.dropdown');
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    if (!$menu.is(e.target) && $menu.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $('.dropdown-content').hide();
    }
});
$("#dd-content a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // changes are HERE <--
    var text = $(this).text();
    var img = $(this).find('img').clone(true);
    $('.dropbtn .lang').text(text);
    $('.dropbtn img').replaceWith(img);
    $("#dd-content a").removeClass('hide');
    $(this).addClass('hide');
    setLanguageCookie();
});
```

Comment: This is not what I meant. I select the language and if I refresh the page, the language dropdown resets to initial. cookie is for nothing right now

Comment: Have you tried it ? with this your code will be at least reached. Which is currently not the case !

Comment: Yes. I tried and nothing happens. Its the same with preventDefault or without it

Comment: Then Show your whole Code + html

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/hg5Laq0m/25/)**.

You've to get the cookies when the page loads and set it as the default like :

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

//GET LANGUAGE COOKIE
function getLanguageCookie() {
    var lang = getCookie('Language') != ""?getCookie('Language'):"EN";
    $('#dd-content').hide();
    $("#dd-content a:contains('"+lang+"')").click();
}

//SET LANGUAGE COOKIE
function setLanguageCookie(Language) {
    var expire=new Date();
    expire=new Date(expire.getTime()+7776000000);
    document.cookie="Language="+Language+"; expires="+expire;
}

// THIS IS FOR THE BURGER MENU TOGGLE
$(".dropbtn").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".dropdown-content, .items").stop().slideToggle(500);
});

// If you click outside dropdown - close dropdown
var $menu = $('.dropdown');
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    if (!$menu.is(e.target) && $menu.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $('.dropdown-content').hide();
    }
});

$("#dd-content a").click(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var img = $(this).find('img').clone(true);

    $('.dropbtn .lang').text(text);
    $('.dropbtn img').replaceWith(img);

    $("#dd-content a").removeClass('hide');
    $(this).addClass('hide');

    setLanguageCookie(text);
});

getLanguageCookie();
```