# Messages translation methods for a Web application in Node and React js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, label, language-translation

**What is the best practise to translate (several languages) messages in a web application ?**

*I use node js for api implementation and backend, and react for the frontend*

1. Front end must make translations before tha page is loaded from properties due to the language
   we have selected (maybe a cost in loading pages until translations are done?)
2. We have saved all messages in database (maybe in a file or json) and frotend asks for it
   asynchronously through API while page is loaded. (a cost in appearing meassge due to asynchronously api call?)
3. Some other way?

Comment: Man, this question is to broad, there is no better way to do translations, just different one, i suggest you to remove this question, or improve it and repost

Comment: Welcome to SO! Perhaps this thread give can you some insights - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084675/how-does-internationalization-work-in-javascript